# Create a json object using array of json objects

Tags: json, postgresql

In postgres Say I have schema as such:

```
table item {
    type varchar(40)
    entity_id bigint
    entity_type varchar(40)
    user_id   bigint
}
```

And I want to query the table to get the info like this:

```
{
    "typeA": {
        "count": 3,
        "me": true
    },
    "typeC": {
        "count": 3,
        "me": false
    },
    "typeE": {
        "count": 3,
        "me": false
    },
    "typeR": {
        "count": 3,
        "me": true
    }
}
```

From a query where the main data is this:

```
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(x)
    FROM
    (
        SELECT type,
        count(*),
        (CASE
            WHEN (SELECT id
                FROM items as i
                WHERE i.entity_type = 'sometype'
                    AND i.entity_id = 234
                    AND i.user_id = 32
                    AND i.type = items.type) is not null
            THEN true
            ELSE false
        END) AS me
        FROM items
        WHERE  items.entity_type = 'sometype'
        AND items.entity_id = 234
        GROUP BY type
    ) as x
```

This returns an array of the info i need type count and me. But I need it formatted like above versus:

```
[
    {
        "type": "typeA",
        "count": 3,
        "me": true
    },
    {
        "type": "typeC",
        "count": 3,
        "me": false
    },
    {
        "type": "typeE",
        "count": 3,
        "me": false
    },
    {
        "type": "typeR",
        "count": 3,
        "me": true
    }
]
```

Which is the current way it is formatted. Have been unable to find a way to build the json object I need. I was able to get three json objects that are like that But I need the three nested in one object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly what you want, but from [PostgreSQL - Aggregate Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-aggregate.html), I would guess, you can try `json_object_agg(name, value)`, e.g.

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT_AGG(type, x)
    FROM
    (
        SELECT type,
        count(*),
        (CASE
            WHEN (SELECT id
                FROM items as i
                WHERE i.entity_type = 'sometype'
                    AND i.entity_id = 234
                    AND i.user_id = 32
                    AND i.type = items.type) is not null
            THEN true
            ELSE false
        END) AS me
        FROM items
        WHERE  items.entity_type = 'sometype'
        AND items.entity_id = 234
        GROUP BY type, me
    ) as x
```

Comment: This works perfectly it adds in the type but that is fine seems necessary. Thanks a ton olaf. :)